# record is not set as dirty when store is updated directly extjs

Tags: extjs, ext.net

I have an Ext.net mvc grid, and a store has been bind to the grid. The grid is collapsed on initial load, in once scenario we will be updating the model in controller and bind model back to the store again as below

**StorePlanDetails.DataSource = Model.CorePlanningRows;
StorePlanDetails.DataBind();**

And while save If i try to get the modified records using Store.getModifiedRecords() method, it is not fetching the updated records.

But once if i expand the grid and if i try to get Store.getModifiedRecords() it is fetching the updated records.

After debugging i found that **dirty** flag is not set if i do not expand the grid.

Is there a way to overcome this issue.

i'm using Extjs 4.0 and Ext.Net MVC.

Comment: How do update the record? Can we see some code?

Comment: Actually we are using Ext.net Mvc, so in once scenario we will be updating the model in controller and bind model back to the store again as below

StorePlanDetails.DataSource = Model.CorePlanningRows;
StorePlanDetails.DataBind();

Comment: If you change the model outside the store the store wouldn't know the model is changed? You just change the source the grid is operating of? It's just a wild guess. Update the record in the store directly, then the store should see the change.